# Bootstrap Carousel Implementation in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the twitter bootstrap 3 slideshow into a template, however, I cannot set the flag variable. The first div requires a class of `active item`, and the rest should just have an `item` class. How can I best achieve this in a for loop?

```
{% for review in reviews|slice:":3" %}
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" %}
     <div class="active item">
    {% else %}
    <div class="item">
    {% endif %}
    <blockquote>
         <p>{{ review.description }}</p>
    </blockquote>
    <label>{{ review.business }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

What I have already tried:

- [Split Django Queryset in template for Bootstrap Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600885/split-django-queryset-in-template-for-bootstrap-carousel)
- [Implementing twitter bootstrap carousel v2.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202452/implementing-twitter-bootstrap-carousel)
- [Dynamic carousel with django and bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314489/dynamic-carousel-with-django-and-bootstrap)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
{% for review in reviews|slice:":3" %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="active item">
    {% else %}
        <div class="item">
    {% endif %}
        <blockquote>
            <p>{{ review.description }}</p>
        </blockquote>
        <label>{{ review.business }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

forloop.first is True if this is the first time through the loop

Comment: Very pragmatic solution. Good job!

Comment: Thank you :) I am trying to be helpful.

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm new to CSS and don't understand this solution. Where in the HTML are you putting this code? Does it replace something else from the HTML on this page? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Ignore the extra styling (relevant for my problem only)

```
# Views.py
events = master_table.objects.all()
events = [events[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(events), 3)]


# template.html
<div id="" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            {% for sublist in events %}
            <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}active{% endif %}">
                <div class="cards-wrapper">
                    {% for event in sublist %}
                    <div class="card {% if forloop.counter0 != 0 %}d-none d-md-block{% endif %}">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/football.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{event.event_title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{event.description}}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: #ff6f3d; border: none;">Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
                data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>

<style>
.cards-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-inner {
  padding: 1em;
}
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  width: 5vh;
  height: 5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for agent in agents %}
    <!-- item -->
        <div class="carousel-item text-center text-light mb-5 {% if forloop.first %} active{% endif %}">
            <img src="{{ agent.image.url }}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mb-3" width="150">
            <p class="px-3">{{ agent.description }}</p>
        </div>
    <!-- end item -->
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please describe how your code exactly solves the problem? What was the origin of the problem? Add more text... Please refer to the [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.